What is $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$?
$\quad$What is the value of the integral
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y?$$
for nonnegative integers $a,b,c$?
$\quad$For example, setting $b=4$, $c=3$, and letting $a$ vary, it seems that $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^a(1-y)^4}{(1-xy)^3}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ takes values according to the following table:
$$\begin{array}{c|cc}\displaystyle
a&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
\iint&\frac7{24},&\frac16,&\pi^2-\frac{39}4,&\frac{119}6-2\pi^2,&\pi^{2}-\frac{235}{24},\\\hline
a&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
\iint&\frac1{15},&\frac7{120},&\frac{109}{2100​},&\frac{131}{2800},&\frac{1879}{44100}​
\end{array}$$
That is, seemingly, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^a(1-y)^4}{(1-xy)^3}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ is rational for all nonnegative integers $a$ except for $a=2,3,4$. At least, that's assuming I didn't fall victim to a rounding error. (These values were computed using Wolfram Alpha, which refused to disclose its computation method.) For another example, at $(a,b,c)=(0,0,1)$, the integral somewhat famously evaluates to $\dfrac{\pi^2}6$.
$\quad$So, what's the pattern? Is there one? I'd be content to know at least when the integral is rational, or what the coefficient of the $\pi^2$ term is when it shows up.
$\quad$It would probably be nicer to know the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^ay^b}{(1-xy)^c}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ for nonnegative integers $a,b,c$, but this seems not to converge most of the time. (In fact I'm unsure how to tell when either integral converges.)

(I'm particularly interested in the special case where $a=2c-1$ and $b=3c-1$.)

In that special case, it is$$
\frac{1}{{6c^2 }}{}_3F_2 \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
{1,c,2c}  \
{1 + 2c,1 + 3c}  \
\end{array};1} \right)$$

@Gary How can this be computed? I know nothing about hypergeometric functions. In particular, this seems to always be $r+s\pi^2$ for rationals $r$ and $s$ - how can these rationals be found?

I asked Wolfram Mathematica. It probably follows from http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2

If $c<1+b$,
\begin{align}J(a,b,c)&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}dxdy\
&=J(1+b-c,b,b+1-a)
\end{align}
Numerically, $J(2;1,1)=\dfrac{1}{4}$

Mathematica gives $$-\frac{-\frac{24 (a-3) (a-2) H_{a-4}}{a-4}-a ((a-14) a+1)+\frac{16}{a-1}+\frac{36}{a}-92}{2 (a-3)^2 (a-2)^2},$$where $H_a$ is the harmonic number at $a$, for the case you mentioned, $b = 4$ and $c = 3$. Interestingly, the function is not defined for $a = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$, but if you take the limit you will get the results on your table, so it somewhat explains why $\pi$ appears among the initial values. Also, this confirms that the function will always yield a rational number for $a \geq 5$. I'd be very surprised if there is a "good" closed formula for all cases of $a,b,c$.

@huh This simplifies to $$\frac{12H_{a-4}}{(a-4)(a-3)(a-2)}+\frac{a^5-15a^4+15a^3+91a^2-144a+36}{2(a-3)^2(a-2)^2(a-1)(a)}$$though I'm not sure how much that helps.

@AkivaWeinberger I ran a few tests with various values of $b$ and $c$ while letting $a$ vary and I noticed that the value of $b$ always indicates when $\pi^2$ stops showing up. That is, for $b$ and $c$ where the integral converges (which I believe is $2+b > c$, but likely converges in other regions as well), the results are always rational when $a > b$. I'm not sure how you could prove that though.

Wait, expanding it into a series demystifies it completely. I'll write something up later, but it should be irrational precisely when $c-1\le a\le b$.
@huh In particular, the case where $b=4,c=3$ is$$-\frac{4!}{2!}\left(\frac{H_a}{(2-a)(3-a)(4-a)}+\frac{H_2}{(a-2)(3-2)(4-2)}+\frac{H_3}{(a-3)(2-3)(4-3)}+\frac{H_4}{(a-4)(2-4)(3-4)}\right),$$unless $a=2,3,4$, in which case we take limits and use the convention $\frac{d}{dn}H_n=\frac{\pi^2}6-1-\frac14-\dotsb-\frac1{n^2}$. The general case replaces the range ${2..4}$ with ${c-1..b}$.

In general the pi part should be $\displaystyle-(-1)^{a+c}\frac{\pi^2}6\frac{b!}{(b-a)!(a-c+1)!(c-1)!}$, if I haven't messed up.

@AkivaWeinberger It seems to be correct. It worked on all cases that I tried.

Let us first assume $(a,b,c)\in \Bbb {(R^+)}^3$. Then
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}dxdy
{=
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{n!\Gamma(c)}x^{n+a}(1-y)^by^ndxdy
\\=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{n!\Gamma(c)}\int_0^1(1-y)^by^ndy
\\=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{n!\Gamma(c)}\frac{\Gamma(b+1)n!}{\Gamma(b+n+2)}
\\=
\frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(c)}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{\Gamma(b+n+2)},
}
$$
where we used $(1-u)^{-c}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{n!\Gamma(c)}u^n$ for $|u|<1$. At this point, due to the non-negativity of the arguments of the summands and integrals, we can deduce the conditions of convergence, which is $c<b+2$. From now on, we assume $(a,b,c)\in (\Bbb Z^{\ge 0})^3$ and $c\ge 1$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{\Gamma(b+n+2)}
{
=
\frac{(n+c-1)!}{(b+n+1)!}
=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{A_i}{b+n+1-i},
}
$$
where
$$
A_i
{=
\lim_{n\to i-b-1}\frac{(b+n+1-i)(n+c-1)!}{(b+n+1)!}
\\=
\lim_{n\to i-b-1}\frac{(b+n+1-i)}{\prod_{j=0}^{b-c+1}(b+n+1-j)}
\\=
\frac{(-1)^{b-c-i+1}}{i!(b-c-i+1)!}.
}
$$
Replacement results in
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}dxdy
{
=
\frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(c)}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+c)}{\Gamma(b+n+2)}
\\=
\frac{b!}{(c-1)!}
\sum_{i=0}^{b-c+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a}\frac{A_i}{b+n-i}
\\=
\frac{b!}{(c-1)!}
\sum_{i=0,i\ne b-a}^{b-c+1}A_i\frac{H_a-H_{b-i}}{a-b+i}
\\+
\frac{b!}{(c-1)!}
A_{b-a}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_a\right)\Bbb{I}_{c-1\le a\le b}
\\=
\binom{b}{c-1}
\sum_{i=0,i\ne a-c+1}^{b-c+1}\binom{b-c+1}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{H_a-H_{c+i-1}}{a-c-i+1}
\\+
\binom{b}{a}\binom{a}{c-1}
(-1)^{a-c+1}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_a\right)\Bbb{I}_{c-1\le a\le b}.
}
$$
Therefore, finally

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^c}dxdy
{
=
\binom{b}{c-1}
\sum_{i=0,i\ne a-c+1}^{b-c+1}\binom{b-c+1}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{H_a-H_{c+i-1}}{a-c-i+1}
\\+
\binom{b}{a}\binom{a}{c-1}
(-1)^{a-c+1}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_a\right)\Bbb{I}_{c-1\le a\le b}.
}
$$

Some special cases
$$
{
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^{b+1}}dxdy
=
\frac{H_a-H_{b}}{a-b}\Bbb{I}_{a\ne b}
+
\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_a\right)\Bbb{I}_{a=b}
\\
\int_0^1\int_0^1
\frac{x^a(1-y)^b}{(1-xy)^{a+1}}dxdy
=
\binom{b}{a}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_a\right)
+
\binom{b}{a}
\sum_{i=1}^{b-a}\binom{b-a}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{H_{a+i}-H_a}{i}
}
$$
Python code for checking the integrity of the results
import numpy as np
from math import factorial
from numpy import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm


def H(n):
    return sum(1/np.arange(1,n+1))

def H2(n):
    return sum(1/np.arange(1,n+1)**2)

def binom(n,m):
    return factorial(n)/factorial(m)/factorial(n-m)

def GammaFuncValue(a,b,c,N=10):
    return sum([1/(n+a+1)/np.prod(np.arange(n+c,n+b+2)) for n in range(0,N)])*factorial(b)/factorial(c-1)

def MonteCarloValue(a,b,c,N=10000):
    x=np.random.rand(N)
    y=np.random.rand(N)
    z=x**a*(1-y)**b/(1-x*y)**c
    return sum(z)/N

def ClosedForm(a,b,c):
    
    values=[]
    
    for i in range(b-c+2):
        
        if i==a-c+1:
            values.append(
                binom(b,a)*binom(a,c-1)*np.cos(np.pi*(a-c+1))*(pi**2/6-H2(a))
                )
        else:
            values.append(
                binom(b,c-1)*binom(b-c+1,i)*np.cos(pi*i)*(H(a)-H(c+i-1))/(a-c-i+1)
                )
    
    return sum(values)




if __name__=="__main__":

    n=100
    progbar=tqdm(total=n,position=0)
    monte_carlo_values=[]
    gamma_func_values=[]
    closed_form_values=[]
    for i in range(n):
        
        a=np.random.randint(1,10)
        b=np.random.randint(1,10)
        c=np.random.randint(1,b+2)
        
        # print("===========================")
        # print(f"a = {a} , b = {b} , c = {c}")
        # print(f"MonteCarloValue = {MonteCarloValue(a,b,c,100000)}")
        # print(f"GammaFuncValue  = {GammaFuncValue(a,b,c,10000)}")
        # print(f"ClosedForm      = {ClosedForm(a,b,c)}")
        monte_carlo_values.append(MonteCarloValue(a,b,c,100000))
        gamma_func_values.append(GammaFuncValue(a,b,c,10000))
        closed_form_values.append(ClosedForm(a,b,c))
        
        progbar.update(1)
                
    plt.plot(monte_carlo_values)
    plt.plot(gamma_func_values)
    plt.plot(closed_form_values)

